# double-precision 64-bit why append zeros to the end?

Tags: javascript, android

I was reading about double-precision 64-bitin javascript and in the examples i saw appending zeros to the end of mantissa and not to the start. No one in the examples explains it.

```
0 00000000010 10000000000000000000000000000000000000000
 why not 
0 00000000010 00000000000000000000000000000000000000001
```

Thank youu

Comment: I think this is by definition. That's just how we define a normalised floating point

Comment: But there must be an explaination

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This convention stems from the way we write binary numbers.
A byte for example has bit locations:

```
128 64 32 16 8 4 2 1
```

If we extended this to include a decimal point as in unsigned fixed precision 16 bit:

```
128 64 32 16 8 4 2 1 . 1/2 1/4 1/8 1/16 1/32 1/64 1/128
```

Remember the numbers are in scientific notation with many representations.
10 could equal 10 * 10^0 or 1 * 10^1 or .1 * 10^2 ...
To make sure numbers are stored in a consistent manner, it was established that an exponent would be chosen such that the mantessa would be a number between 1 and 2(not inclusive of the 2).

To express the matessa in binary, it is in the form:

```
1 1/2 1/4 1/8 1/16 1/32 1/64 1/128 ...
```

This form fits the traditional binary scheme as described above.